# Apache word document creation fail

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

```
package docx;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.OutputStream;  
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;  
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;  
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;  
public class Letsgo {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {  
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();  
        try(OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Javatpoint.docx")) {  
            document.write(fileOut);  
            System.out.println("File created");  
        }catch(Exception e) {  
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
        }  
    }  `enter code here`
}
```

[image]

> This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

I tried to look up solutions but none of them worked.

Comment: You need additional libraries to this. I recommend to use maven to that transitive dependencies also make it to your classpath.

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing jar in your libs.  Those yellow lines under your imports is telling you it has no idea what those classes are.

Comment: Okay so i added maven dependacies restarted eclipse and now it works!!!

Comment: Great. Since the answer you received solved your issue, you can mark it as "correct", by clicking on the check mark beside the answer, to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.